# Three max subject marks in a marksdetail table in oracle

Tags: oracle10g

Hi there are two tables one name st_detail having column id,class,name,address,contact,DOB and the second table marks contain id, class,subject1,subject2,subject3,subject4 primary key of both the table is ID,class. Now I need to show ID,class and the three subjects with maximum values. Can anyone help

Comment: Please provide some sample data for table `marks` together with the expected result.

Comment: ID   Class   sub1   sub2  sub3  sub4

Comment: ID   Class   sub1   sub2  sub3  sub4 are the six columns.now each row will show the ID and class column with the three subject column with the top 3 values